# Is it possible to monitor hadoop, hbase and yarn using monit tool?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hadoop-yarn, monit

I want to monitor some services such that, those services needs to restart when they goes down and I found an amazing tool `monit`. It works fine for `Zookeeper` since I got a condition like `matching "QuorumPeerMain"` as shown below in `monitrc` file

```
check process Zookeeper matching "QuorumPeerMain"
        start program = "path/to/zkServer.sh start"
        stop program  = "path/to/zkServer.sh stop"
```

In the sameway, I want to monitor these : **hadoop, yarn and hbase**

```
check process Hadoop matching "?"
        start program = "startorstop.sh start"  #equivalent to start-dfs.sh
        stop program  = "startorstop.sh stop"   #equivalent to stop-dfs.sh
```

What should be written in the place of **?**

These are the questions

- In the hadoop case, there may be a chance any one of these going down `NameNode`, `DataNode`, `SecondaryNameNode`. [Monit Doc](https://www.mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Service-checks) says that *"The top-most matching parent with highest uptime is selected"*. For e.g., If DataNode goes down, it  still considers NameNode and won't try to restart `hadoop`. Another option was using pid file and I am not able to find hadoop's pid file in `/var/run/`
- I want something like a top to bottom approach (not exactly). After starting `zookeeper` only, I want to start the remaining services like `hbase`, `hadoop` and `yarn`

Comment: Cloudera CDH uses SystemD for this purpose, last I checked, but you can run `ps -ef | grep java` and search for the main classes that are being used for each process. And compare that with  `jps` if you are trying to find the equivalent of `QuorumPeerMain`

Comment: `QuorumPeerMain` works fine for Zookeeper, but I am looking for `Hadoop` which have a subprocess like `NameNode`, `SecondaryNameNode` and `DataNode`. If any of these subprocess goes down, I need to restart `Hadoop`

Comment: And it does. I told you how to find them all from your own running processes. Those aren't subprocesses, each is a top level process that should individually have start/stop commands, not start-all or start-dfs  for example. Rather use `hadoop namenode -daemon`, I think

Comment: Exactly, got your point and that is what I needed but I got the same in diff approach. For `Hadoop`  I am using `hadoop-daemon.sh start/stop namenode/datanode`, and for `HBase` using `hbase-daemon.sh start/stop master/regionserver` and for `yarn` using `yarn-daemon.sh start/stop nodemanager`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a way to start `NameNode`, `DataNode`, `SecondaryNameNode` independently using shell scripts i.e., `hadoop-daemon.sh` So in my monit conf `NameNode` looks like

Credits to @OneCricketeer for the comment, So that I can find a way to start these process independently

```
check process NameNode matching "NameNode"
    start program = "startorstop.sh start"  #hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode
    stop program  = "startorstop.sh stop"   #hadoop-daemon.sh stop namenode
    group hadoop
```

and for another part of my question, I got `depends` option. For more detail take a look here [Service Dependencies](https://www.mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#SERVICE-DEPENDENCIES)
. In my case, I wanted to restart `HRegionServer` whenever `DataNode` goes down. So below conf works

```
check process HRegionServer matching "HRegionServer"
    start program = "startorstop.sh start"  #hbase-daemon.sh start regionserver
    stop program =  "startorstop.sh stop"   #hbase-daemon.sh stop regionserver
    depends on DataNode

check process DataNode matching "DataNode"
    start program = "startorstop.sh start"  #hbase-daemon.sh start datanode
    stop program =  "startorstop.sh stop"   #hbase-daemon.sh stop datanode
```

Comment: I still think SystemD / SysInit scripts would be better than an external dependency on monit